# Windows Update service in services automaticaly changed to disabled. cannot change it manually eaither

Tags: windows-update, windows-services

I think this happened after 20H2 update. Windows Update and Windows Update Medic services are automatically disabled. I cannot even change the status into automatically or manual and start the service manually. If I change the status into something else (automatically or manual from disabled), after refreshing the services list it shows disabled again. Screenshots are attached below.

I had
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uzTX.png) issue in updates section in settings app. That's why I checked in services,

[In services section shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1ts.png)

Comment: From admin elevated cmd run `sfc /scannow`, let that complete then run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, now reboot and see if the services start automatically or allow you to change to do so.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I tried it dear.. Didn't work

Comment: Try the troubleshooter steps in the Microsoft article I posted.

Comment: @Pumayk26 I suggest you perform an [offline Windows Defender AV scan](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help-protect-my-pc-with-microsoft-defender-offline-9306d528-64bf-4668-5b80-ff533f183d6c) and see if it turns up anything. Also if the Windows Update Medic Service is also disabled, you might ensure you are not running some sort of Windows Update blocker as per this example https://windowsreport.com/windows-update-medic-service as discussed in the **How to disable the Windows Update Medic Service** section there. Let me know what results you get from there.

Comment: Also, look over the event viewer application and system logs and tell me if you see anything error wise there that seems to be related if you still have the problems after the offline AV scan and checking to confirm this system is not configured with some software that specifically tries to block and prevent Windows from updating or being repaired.

Comment: Before you take the drastic step of reinstalling Windows, can you provide the value of *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc* and provide a screenshot of the dependencies of both of those services?

Comment: Ramhound says I am wrong and I deleted my post. I do not have Update Medic on any of my Windows 10 computers that I can see.

Comment: @FormerlyPimpJuiceIT I haven't tried to block Windows Update. I didn't even metered connection enabled. also never changed the status to disabled in any of those two services.. I just realized that I didn't get any minor updates for a while so I tried to check for updates manually. That's how I find the issue in Windows Update issue in settings app. Then I look in the services and found that services are disabled. Last update I got is 20H2 update..

Comment: @Ramhound the key values https://i.imgur.com/t6F9tLO.png

Comment: @John May be your os customized for lite usage dear.. It's ok. Thanks for your ideas.. :)

Comment: @Pumayk26 - What about the dependencies for the service?  Set the value of Start to 2, it’s currently set to 4, which means it’s disabled.  However, this behavior, points to system integrity issues. Make sure the Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service is enabled/running

Comment: Also set the Start key for UsoSvc to 2 if isn’t already

Comment: @Ramhound RPC service is running. UsoSvc is already 2. I changed the start value to 2 in WaaSMedicSVC then closed the registry editor and reopened. Start value is changed to 4 again. :(

Comment: @FormerlyPimpJuiceIT I've installed bitdefender total security. May I do a system scan.? Will this script effect to my files..?

Comment: [This](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-WindowsUpdateps1-e0c5eb78) script is a last resort solution.  This should be in addition to the script Juice IT suggested.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I run this..? Just past in Powershell and hit enter..?

Comment: Instructions are included

Comment: I got some errors while running the script. But after restart, I can access windows update section in settings app. But still saying "One of the update services is not running properly, but you can try to run a troubleshooter to fix the problem. Go to Start button > Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot, and then select Windows Update.". Also Windows Update service in services is still disabled and cannot change as before.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was in front of my eyes.. There is an application installed called "StopUpdates10".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTAOE.png)

I didn't install it my self.. When I found it I googled the service name and I found [this](https://greatis.com/stopupdates10/) application. But in my pc has installed it as a service. There is no any interfaces. I suspect that this service is installed by another software I installed. I cannot even find it in Programs and Features. I think all I can do is delete the service manually.